# Constrained extensions methods produces ambigious call

Tags: c#, generics

Let's suppose we have two unrelated interfaces

```
public interface IFirst
{

}

public interface ISecond
{

}
```

And extension methods with the same name but constrained to each interface.

```
public static class IFirstExtensions
{
    public static void DoIt<TFirst>(this TFirst model)
        where TFirst : IFirst
    {

    }
}

public static class ISecondExtensions
{
    public static void DoIt<TSecond>(this TSecond model)
        where TSecond : ISecond
    {

    }
}
```

When I'm trying to work with IFirst instance:

```
IFirst first = ...;
first.DoIt();
```

Then I get error:

> "CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'IFirstExtensions.DoIt(TFirst)' and 'ISecondExtensions.DoIt(TSecond)'".

That is strange. Looks like both methods are visible in this scope. But if I'll name them differently, e.g.:

```
public static class IFirstExtensions
{
    public static void DoFirst<TFirst>(this TFirst model)
        where TFirst : IFirst
    {

    }
}

public static class ISecondExtensions
{
    public static void DoSecond<TSecond>(this TSecond model)
        where TSecond : ISecond
    {

    }
}
```

Then constraint works and the second method is not visible raising compilation error:

```
IFirst first = ...;
first.DoSecond();
```

So looks like that constraint staisfying conditions works differenly when detecting ambiguity and when calling. But in C# spec I found only one chapter related to this subject stricly describing how constrains are working. Is this a bug in compiler or I miss something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generic constraints are *not part of a method signature*. Both methods are exactly the same when it comes to overload resolution and therefore an ambigous call error is generated.

> Specifically, the signature of a method consists of its name, the number of type parameters and the number, modifiers, and types of its formal parameters (**C# 5.0 Specification, 10.6 Methods**)
>
> For the purposes of signature comparisons any type-parameter-constraints-clauses are ignored, as are the names of the method’s type-parameters, but the number of generic type parameters is relevant (**ECMA-334, 25.6.1 Generic method signatures**)

To put it clearer, when it comes to overload resolution, both extension methods are simply:

```
public static void DoFirst<T>(this T model)
```

Also, do notice that the issue is not related exclusively to extension methods. Consider the following example where two generic methods with the same signature but different constraints are declared inside the same class:

```
class Foo
{
    void Bar<T>(Blah blah) where T: Frob { }
    void Bar<T>(Blah blah) where T: Blob { } //CS0111 error
}
```

You will get a compile time error:

> CS0111    Type 'Foo' already defines a member called 'Bar' with the same parameter types.

Comment: Foo class differs from the usage of unrelated classes I told about. I would see my version closed into signatures like: Bar(Frob blah), Bar(Blob blah). That's why instead of CS0111 they compiled without problems. And if you take a look into MethodInfo->Signature->Arguments[0], you'll see absolutely different types with different values in ImplementedInterfaces property. So in runtime the signature is different and it contains constraints.

Comment: But you're right. I missed the point in the spec, that generic constrains are officially ignored for signatures. And this is ridiculous. If I will extend IFirst/ISecond inrerfaces - it is ok. If I'll put these contracts as constraints - it's not.

Comment: @stan No, the signatures are the same, the error is different because the methods are defined in different classes. When resolving the call both methods are in the candidate set and thats the moment when the identital  signatures issue crops up and the call is flagged as ambiguous. The error is not given before because you can always define explicitly the static class implementing the extension method when calling it as a regular static method. This would also be the case with  a class implemententig two interfaces with the same method signature and two different constraints.

Comment: @Stan you could always desambiguate calling the method through a variable typed with the desired interface.

Comment: @Stan when both methods are defined in the same class there is no way you are ever going to be able to desambiguate the call so the error is given at once.